# can't docker-compose up all at once on ec2 t2.micro

Tags: docker, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I have 3 services in my `compose.yaml`, 2 web apps and nginx proxy manager,

on ec2 if I call `sudo docker-compose up` it will eventually freeze and the instance will become unresponsive ( I have to reboot it )

and my current solution is to call

```
sudo docker-compose up webapp1 
(wait to finish about 1 minute)

sudo docker-compose up webapp2
(wait to finish)

sudo docker-compose up
(success)
```

is this a known issue?, am I hitting some timeouts? is there another solution for this?